# P Element found or not in cypress

Tags: node.js, testing, cypress

I want to check `p` tag exists in parent tag or not, Currently its finding the `p` tag but problem is that some of `li` tag have no `p` tag so it throw error. I don't need error I want to know if have error or not having `p` tag then set variable `keyValue` to false or if have `p` element then set variable `keyValue` to its text which is inside the `p` tag.

Here is HTML code:

```
 <ul class="list-inline">
  <li>
    <div class="key-info-icon">
      <span>Sleeps</span> <br /><i class="fi flaticon-sleeps"></i>
    </div>
    <p>6</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="key-info-icon">
      <span>Bedrooms</span> <br /><i class="fi flaticon-bedrooms"></i>
    </div>
    <p>3 Rooms</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="key-info-icon">
      <span>Min Nights</span> <br /><i class="fi flaticon-min-nights"></i>
    </div>
    <p>7 (peak)<br />3 (off peak)</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="key-info-icon">
      <span>Children</span> <br /><i class="fi flaticon-child-friendly"></i>
    </div>
    <p>Yes</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="key-info-icon">
      <span>WiFi</span> <br /><i class="fi flaticon-wifi"></i>
    </div>
    <p>Yes</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="key-info-icon">
      <span>Dogs</span> <br /><i class="fi flaticon-dog"></i>
    </div>
    <p>
      Yes <br />
      2 Dogs
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="key-info-icon text-center">
      <span>Access</span> <br /><i class="fi flaticon-stairs"></i>
    </div>
    <p>Stairs</p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="key-info-icon">
      <span>Swimming Pool</span> <br /><i class="fi flaticon-swimming-pool"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="key-info-icon">
      <span>Log Burner</span> <br /><i class="fi flaticon-logburner"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my cypress code:

```
 cy.get(".keyInfo >  ul > li").each(($el, index) => {
    cy.get($el).find("span").as("keyName");
    let keyValue;
    cy.get("@keyName").then(($span) => {
      cy.get($span).parent().siblings();     

      let tempData = {
        [`"${$span.text()}"`]: "test",
      };
      keyTempData.keyInfo.push(tempData);
    });
    data.keyInfo = keyTempData;
  });
```

Any idea how it can be achived? `cy.get($span).parent().siblings();` this is throwing error if there is no `p` tag. I have also tried `cy.get($span).parent().parent().find('p');` this is also doing same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
cy.get(".keyInfo > ul > li").each($el => {

  cy.wrap($el).find('.key-info-icon > span').then($span => {
    if ($el.find('p').length) {
      cy.wrap($el).find('p').then($p => {
        keyTempData.keyInfo.push({ [$span.text()]: $p.text() });
      });
    } else {
      keyTempData.keyInfo.push({ [$span.text()]: 'NA' });
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Ok I will try that soon for now I have solved like below

Comment: cy.get(".keyInfo >  ul > li").each(($el, index) => {
    cy.get($el).find("span").as("keyName");
    cy.get("@keyName").then(($span) => {
      let keyValue = false;
      cy.get($span)
        .parent()
        .parent()
        .then(($val) => {
          if ($val.has("p")) {
            keyValue = $val.find("p").text();
            let tempData = {
              [`"${$span.text()}"`]: keyValue,
            };
            keyTempData.keyInfo.push(tempData);
          }
        });
    });
    data.keyInfo = keyTempData;
  });

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is `cy.get('p')` fails when `<p>` does not exist, but you can avoid this by substituting a jQuery expression using `Cypress.$`.

Essentially, you just want to map the `<li>` content into an array of key/value pairs, which is easier to do with `.then()` rather than `.each()`.

Assigning to a variable within a `.then()` can be problematic, you would want to do this in a `beforeEach()` or assign the result to a Cypress alias.

```js
cy.get(".keyInfo >  ul > li")
  .then(($els, index) => {

    const keyInfos = $els.map((index, el) => {

      const spanText = Cypress.$(el).find('span').text();

      const pText = Cypress.$(el).find('p').text()
        .replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ' ')                  // remove <br/>
        .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')                       // remove multiple spaces
        .trim();

      return { [`${spanText}`]: pText || false }
    })
    return keyInfos;
  })
  .as('keyTempData')

cy.get('@keyTempData')
  .then($data => console.log(Array.from($data)))

/*
  0: {Sleeps: "6"}
  1: {Bedrooms: "3 Rooms"}
  2: {Min Nights: "7 (peak)3 (off peak)"}
  3: {Children: "Yes"}
  4: {WiFi: "Yes"}
  5: {Dogs: "Yes 2 Dogs"}
  6: {Access: "Stairs"}
  7: {Swimming Pool: false}
  8: {Log Burner: false}
*/
```